# Compute value at risk from DCC GARCH (in R)

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, garch, quantiles

I am struggling to obtain the Value at Risk from my DCC GARCH analysis. I have done the following code:

```r
SMF.frame <- data.frame(df_fuldperiode$spot_log_returns [2:2217], df_fuldperiode$monthly_log_returns [2:2217])
sspec <- ugarchspec ( mean.model = list( armaOrder = c ( 5 , 4 )))
mspec <- ugarchspec ( mean.model = list( armaOrder = c ( 0 , 1 )))
smspec <- multispec ( c (sspec , mspec) )
smfit <- multifit (smspec, data = SMF.frame)

dccsmspec <- dccspec(uspec=smspec, dccOrder = c (1,1), VAR = TRUE, distribution ="mvt")
dccsmfit <- dccfit(dccsmspec, data = SMF.frame, 
                   fit.control = list(eval.se=TRUE, fit = smfit))

dccsmfit

plot(dccsmfit)



dcc_rfore <- dccroll(dccsmspec, 
                     data= SMF.frame, 
                     n.ahead = 1, 
                     forecast.length = forecast_len, 
                     refit.every = 5, )
```

I wonder how I can extract the 95% VaR and 99% VaR. Can anyone help with this issue?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please format the script and other materials correctly to make them legible.

Comment: VaR of what? Each asset individually? In such a case, you do not need DCC; the univariate GARCH models will do the job. Check out the `calculate.VaR` method described on p. 87 of the [rugarch](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/rugarch.pdf) help files.

Comment: Also ["Fitting and Predicting VaR based on an ARMA-GARCH Process"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qrmtools/vignettes/ARMA_GARCH_VaR.html) by Marius Hofert seems to be quite relevant.

Comment: @RichardHardy , I'm evaluating hedging strategies at the Nordic power market. I have model the DCC GARCH fro wich I think i can recireve the VaR for the protfolio

Comment: So you have some portfolio weights and then want a VaR for the portfolio?

Comment: I have calculated the joint Alpha and beta for daily returns for spot prices and monthly future contract prices with the DCC GARCH process. The joint alpha = 0.001383 and the joint beta=0.966262. 

I thought from there, that it could calculate the VaR from information obtained from the DCC GARCH.

Comment: i have attached the 1% Var limits, but i dont know how to extract the value or how to change them to 5%

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/429391, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130227. See more links in the column to the right.

Comment: There is a nearly duplicate question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596550.

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to retrieve the values from the plot nor how they were calculated in the first place. However, this is not a problem.

Here is a general method for estimating portfolio VaR from a DCC-GARCH model for the components of the portfolio. It will work regardless of the specifications of the individual GARCH models and the DCC part.

- Simulate a $k$-variate 1-step-ahead realization from the multivariate DCC-GARCH process. (You can use `dccsim` or `fScenario` methods from the `rmgarch` package for this.)
- Add the $p$ components up using appropriate weights to obtain the realization of the portfolio of interest.
- Carry the former two steps out a large number of times (e.g. $n=1000$ or $n=10000$ times).
- Obtain the empirical $\alpha$-level quantile of the $n$ portfolio realizations. (You can use the `quantile` function for this.) This is your estimate of the portfolio's $\alpha$-level Value at Risk.

In the special case of normality assumptions for both the individual GARCH models and the DCC part (which is not the case in your example), you could calculate the VaR analytically. Note that a linear combination of scalar components of a multivariate normal random vector is a normal random variable. The expected value `mu` and the variance `sigma^2` can be obtained from the usual formulas for a weighted sum of random variables. Then you would take the quantile of a normal distribution with that mean and variance via `qnorm(p=alpha, mean=mu, sd=sigma)`.