# How to calculate VaR on DCC GARCH?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, garch, quantiles

I am using a DCC (and CCC) GARCH model to model volatility of electricity price returns (using spot and futures) i.e. I have more variables in my model. I need to calculate VaR using these models but I do not know how to calculate it in R. Does anyone know how to do this procedure?

Code used:

```r
SMF.frame <- data.frame(df_fuldperiode$spot_log_returns, df_fuldperiode$monthly_log_returns)
sspec <- ugarchspec ( mean.model = list( armaOrder = c ( 5 , 4 )))
mspec <- ugarchspec ( mean.model = list( armaOrder = c ( 0 , 1 )))
smspec <- multispec ( c (sspec , mspec) )
smfit <- multifit (smspec, data = SMF.frame)

dccsmspec <- dccspec(uspec=smspec, dccOrder = c (1,1), distribution ="mvt")
dccsmfit <- dccfit(dccsmspec, data = SMF.frame,
                   fit.control = list(eval.se=TRUE, fit = smfit))

dccsmfit

#forecast

dcc_rfore <- dccroll(dccsmspec, 
                     data= SMF.frame, 
                     n.ahead = 1, 
                     forecast.length = 500, 
                     refit.every = 5, )

dcc_rfore
```

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596323. It already has an answer. (The answer has no upvotes, though, so technically cannot be proposed as a duplicate.)

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks but I do not understand the reply in the linked answer. I hoped there would be a simple code, that could calculate it for me without having to do a lot if different procedures first. Best emma